# Get the value of all the EditText from ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a Listview inside my Layout and I want to get the value of all the EditText from that ListView whether its visible on the screen or not.

I am doing it in following way:

```
String Quantity = "";
for (int i=0; i<lv_order.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {

        View childView = lv_order.getAdapter().getView(i,null,lv_order);
        View childView2 = getViewByPosition(i,lv_order);

        EditText editText = (EditText) childView.findViewById(R.id.layout_model_ETQuantity);
        TextView textView = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.layout_model_Model);

        EditText editText1 = (EditText) childView2.findViewById(R.id.layout_model_ETQuantity);

        if(editText.length() > 0) {
            Quantity = Quantity + " " + editText.getText().toString();
        }
}

public View getViewByPosition(int position, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (position < firstListItemPosition || position > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = position - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

Using childView2 I am getting the correct value of EditText that are visible, but using ChildView1 I am always getting the value of EditText as empty and the length is always 0.

I have also tried using

```
View childView = lv_order.getChildAt(i);
```

inside for loop but the application crashes when it tries to get the value of ListView child that is not visible.

**Update**

**Adapter Class**

```
public class porder_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<POrder> {

private List<POrder> items;

public porder_adapter(Context context, int resource, List<POrder> items) {

    super(context, resource, items);

    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView != null) {
        return convertView;
    }
    else{
        View v = convertView;

        TextView modelNo = null;

        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.layout_model, null);

        modelNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_model_Model);

        POrder p = items.get(position);

        if (p != null) {

            if (modelNo != null)
                modelNo.setText("" + p.getModelNo());
        }
        return v;
    }
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

}
```

Comment: ListView recycling the views, so you can't retrieve views that not visible.
Same view will be used for different items in your adapter.

Comment: @Alex so how to retrieve those values?

Comment: You should keep them inside adapter items and then retrieve from the items itself and not the views

Comment: @Alex I have updated my question and added my adapter class. What should I do in that?

Comment: @Alex any update?

Comment: When you entering the values in the edittext you should save the entered values inside the items itself.